# Disable task creation/display when an email is "flagged" in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, to-do, gtd

I want to flag certain emails in my inbox for follow-up, but I don't want them to display in my tasks (which is the default behavior).

You can right-click the newly-created task that references the email you just flagged and select "Remove from List" but this removes the flag in your email. You can also move the emails to a separate .pst folder that is outside of the .pst/.ost/Exchange file that contains your To-Do List - but I want to keep them all in my default Exchange Inbox/.ost.

Is it possible to prevent flagged emails from showing up in your task or To-Do List in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the tasks area and right click `arrange by` and go to `filter`

1. Go to Advanced tab
2. Down at Define more criteria
3. Drop down Field - All mail fields - Message Class
4. Condition: `contains`
5. Value: `task`
6. Add to list

Now it will only show tasks, not flagged emails

Comment: This dialog can be found at Ribbon->View->View Settings->Filter->Advanced (Outlook 2010)